# Github-pages relative links not working when custom domain is used

Tags: http-status-code-404, markdown, github-pages, relative-path, github-flavored-markdown

I'm using Github-pages with no Jekyll, just bare markdown `.md` files.

To link from that `.md` to some folder inside my repo I'm using relative links.

Why relative links? I was using absolute links like https://github.com/USER_NAME/REPO_NAME/blob/master/FOLDER_NAME but then I changed my repo name and every link stopped to work.

This is why I moved to relative links but then when I checked how the page works under custom domain -> every link stopped to work.

By "stopped" to work I mean: now when I go to www.CUSTOM_DOMAIN.com/REPO_NAME/FOLDER_NAME I'm getting 404.

**EDIT 1:**
When I was trying to edit this question for [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798379/github-pages-relative-links-not-working-when-custom-domain-is-used?noredirect=1#comment88606187_50798379) I realized the problem is different:
- links to files works fine
- but links to folders doesn't work, i.e. REPO_NAME is not added to URI, there should be:

```
www.CUSTOM_DOMAIN.com/REPO_NAME/FOLDER_NAME
```

while actually there is:

```
www.CUSTOM_DOMAIN.com/FOLDER_NAME.
```

So my repo looks like this:

```
REPO_NAME/
├── README.md
├── FOLDER_NAME/
│   ├── FOLDERFILE.md
```

So the link in my `README.md` is (NOK):

```
[some string for folder](/FOLDER_NAME)
(which is unwrapped by github-pages-engine to)
www.CUSTOM_DOMAIN.com/FOLDER_NAME
```

It works fine when I link to a file, like this (OK):

```
[some string for file](/FOLDER_NAME/FOLDERFILE.md)
(which is unwrapped by github-pages-engine to)
www.CUSTOM_DOMAIN.com/REPO_NAME/FOLDER_NAME.html
```

**EDIT 2:**
the page I'm trying to fix is NOT the organization/user page so it should have REPO_NAME in the path.

**EDIT 3:**
I changed links to remove leading slash and they still does not work. Now link in my `README.md` is (NOK):

```
[some string for folder](FOLDER_NAME/)
(which is unwrapped by github-pages-engine to)
www.CUSTOM_DOMAIN.com/REPO_NAME/FOLDER_NAME
```

or (also NOK):

```
[some string for folder](./FOLDER_NAME/)
(which is unwrapped by github-pages-engine to)
www.CUSTOM_DOMAIN.com/REPO_NAME/FOLDER_NAME
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question and provide some example relative links (both source page and target page). It would also help if you indicated what absolute URL you expected the relative link to point to and where is is actually pointing.

Comment: @Waylan question edited, I hope this is not too abstract now!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You are not using relative URLs.
2. You are not accounting for the server root being different with a custom domain.

## Relative URLs

A relative URL is a path which is relative to the current location. However, a URL which starts with a slash is not relative to the current location. The opening slash indicates a path from the server root. In other words, to "normalize" the URL, simply prepend the domain.

Therefore, for a link to be relative to the current location, it cannot begin with a slash. Using your example structure, any links in the `FOLDERFILE.md` file would look like this:

```
[REPO_NAME](../)          <= step back one directory
[README.md](../README.md) <= step back one directory
[FOLDER_NAME](./)         <= the current directory
```

And any links in the `README.md` file would look like this"

```
[REPO_NAME](./)
[FOLDER_NAME](FOLDER_NAME/)
[FOLDERFILE.md](FOLDER_NAME/FOLDERFILE.md)
```

If it helps, you could start all URLs with the current directory (`./`). While not necessary, some people find it more readable. In that case, the `README.md` file would look like this"

```
[REPO_NAME](./)
[FOLDER_NAME](./FOLDER_NAME/)
[FOLDERFILE.md](./FOLDER_NAME/FOLDERFILE.md)
```

## Server Root

It is important to understand the difference between the server root and your site's root. When they are the same, absolute links will work fine. However, when they are different, only true relative links will work across the two.

When you set up GitHub pages using the GitHub provided domain, your site is hosted at `https://USERNAME.github.io/REPO_NAME`. In that case, the server root is at `USERNAME.github.io/` and that's where `/` points to. However, your site's root is in the subdirectory `/REPO_NAME`. Therefore for absolute URLs to work, the must include `/REPO_NAME/` in them.

However, when you set up a custom domain, then the server root and the site's root are at the same location: `https://example.com/`. There is no `REPO_NAME` subdirectory. The contents of `REPO_NAME` are at `/`.

To illustrate, the following URLs point to the same location depending on whether you are using a GitHub domain or a custom domain.

```
GitHub Domain                        | Custom Domain
------------------------------------ | --------------------------
/REPO_NAME/                          | /
/REPO_NAME/README.md                 | /README.md
/REPO_NAME/FOLDER_NAME/              | /FOLDER_NAME/
/REPO_NAME/FOLDER_NAME/FOLDERFILE.md | /FOLDER_NAME/FOLDERFILE.md
```

And that difference is why you need to use true relative URLS -- URLs which do not start with a `/`.

Comment: I added edited the question (EDIT 2) because I think it may influence the answer.

Comment: Your edits don't make any sense to me. What is the full address of README.md when you are viewing it in your browser?

Comment: README.md is just standard read me file added when repo creation from github web interface; it's (as always) at the repo root

Comment: Yes, but what is the URL in the address bar of your browser when you are visiting that page?

Comment: No, what is the address when you are viewing the page on GitHub pages (with your custom domain)?

Comment: then it's www.CUSTOM_DOMAIN.com/REPO_NAME; when I'm viewing my USER page it's www.CUSTOM_DOMAIN.com (without REPO_NAME)

Comment: I don't understand how either of those addresses point to `README.md`. Are you sure that is the full URL?

Comment: it does not point to it directly, github automagially takes README.md and uses it as index.html

Comment: Which of those URLs points to README.md? If both of them do, then that's your problem. The relative URLs would be different at each location to point to the same file.

Comment: this one www.CUSTOM_DOMAIN.com/REPO_NAME points to the README.md we are talking about in this entire question; this one www.CUSTOM_DOMAIN.com points to separate repository (with my user's account github-pages web apge)

Comment: Unfortunately, Github scrambles the link so a relative link ends up being a broken link